# AnythingSlider - How to make first slide not to be taken on count on numbered controls

Tags: javascript, customization, slideshow, anythingslider

I'm creating a slider with AnythingSlider and I need the first slide not to be considered in navigation: I need the numbers to start counting from `1` from the second slide on. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Would this slide #0 still be part of the autoplay-loop, have its own hashtag and so on? Or do you only want to show some content before the actual "slideshow" starts?

Comment: I need it to be part of the slideshow (autoplay-loop), it's just like a cover/preview for the rest of the slides.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `navigationFormatter` option as follows:

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({
  navigationFormatter : function(index, panel){
    return index + 1;
  }
});
```

Then if you are using the [latest version](https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider) from github, you could hide the first tab using this css:

```
ul.thumbNav li.first { display: none; }
```

Comment: That only offsets the numbers in the navigation controls, but doesn't make the first one actually be out of the count.

Comment: Hmm, ok maybe I'm not understanding what you want. I re-read everything here and I'm still confused.